# Access values of table using foreign key, in django

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I have 3 tables in my database. 
1. users
2. sessiontokens
3. post

I have used foreign key to refer to user table in both sessiontoken and post.
I want to check in accesstoken table if a query exists and get corresponding user_id value from it.

models

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class SessionToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    session_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def create_token(self):
        self.session_token = uuid.uuid4()


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='user_images')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is what happens,
a session_token is generated everytime a user logs in.
and we check if the user is logged in right now or not using the following function.

```
def check_validation(request):
if request.COOKIES.get('session_token'):
    session = SessionToken.objects.filter(session_token=request.COOKIES.get('session_token'))
    if session:
        return session
else:
    return None
```

I want to set user_id in post table from matching the user_id in sessiontoken from above function

```
def upload_view(request):
    usr = check_validation(request)

    if usr:
        if request.method == "GET":
            form = PostForm()
            return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                pic = form.cleaned_data.get('image')
                title = form.cleaned_data.get('caption')
                post = PostForm().instance

                post.user = usr 

                post.image = pic
                post.caption = title
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing *any* of this. Django already has a built-in session framework. And more importantly you *certainly* shouldn't be managing users yourselves, in particular you must not store passwords as plain text. Let Django take care of user management.

Comment: Thank you so much.